# Objective C: Begin date and end date UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I have two `UIDatePickers` and two `UITextField`. 
One `UIDatePicker` and `textField` show the begin date + time. 
The second `UIDatePicker` and `textField` shows the end date +time.

The problem i'm facing is that i need to connect the two `DatePickers` so that the end date cannot exceed the begin date + time. Also that there cannot be more than 24hours between the begin and end date + time. What do i need to do in order to achieve this? How do i connect the two `UIDatePicker`, and prevent the dates + time from exceeding each other if this is possible?

My `UIDatePicker` pops up when the `textField` is being clicked (instead of the keyboard).

I'm still learning, so please bear with me. I'm trying my best to understand.
Before anyone tells me this post already exists, it doesn't, not the way i want my `UIDatePicker` to work. (Please compare my code to theirs, its different)

The code i have for the `UIDatePicker` is :

.h file:

```
@

interface TaakToevoegen : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate>{
    UIDatePicker *beginTijdPicker;
    UIDatePicker *eindTijdPicker; 
}

//TextField for both begindate and enddate. 
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *beginTijdTextField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *eindTijdTextField;
```

.m file:

```
beginTijdPicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
beginTijdPicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;

//Sets time to 24hour notation instead of AM & PM
NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"NL"];
[beginTijdPicker setLocale:locale];

[self.beginTijdTextField setInputView:beginTijdPicker];
UIToolbar *toolBar=[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[toolBar setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                          style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                         target:self
                                                         action:@selector(ShowSelectedDate1)];

UIBarButtonItem *space= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                      target:nil
                                                                      action:nil];
[toolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:space, doneBtn, nil]];
[self.beginTijdTextField setInputAccessoryView:toolBar];


    -(void)ShowSelectedDate1{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"dd MMM HH:mm"];

    self.beginTijdTextField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:beginTijdPicker.date]];
    [self.beginTijdTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Enddate (same as begindate but different names):

```
eindTijdPicker=[[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
eindTijdPicker.datePickerMode=UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;

//Sets time to 24hour notation instead of AM & PM
NSLocale *locale1 = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"NL"];
[eindTijdPicker setLocale:locale1];

[self.eindTijdTextField setInputView:eindTijdPicker];
UIToolbar *toolBar1=[[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
[toolBar1 setTintColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
UIBarButtonItem *doneBtn1=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done"
                                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                          target:self
                                                          action:@selector(ShowSelectedDate2)];

UIBarButtonItem *space1= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                       target:nil
                                                                       action:nil];
[toolBar1 setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:space1, doneBtn1, nil]];
[self.eindTijdTextField setInputAccessoryView:toolBar1];

-(void)ShowSelectedDate2{
    NSDateFormatter *formatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter1 setDateFormat:@"dd MMM HH:mm"];

    self.eindTijdTextField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [formatter1 stringFromDate:eindTijdPicker.date]];
    [self.eindTijdTextField resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: do u enter any info in textfield or do u just use textfield to display some info ?

Comment: textfield displays the chosen date after clicking done on the UIDatePicker

Comment: so if you choose todays date in picker1, then picker 2 should have the end date/last date for selection as tomorrow date ?

Comment: This is a non-trivial issue.  Do you understand about reacting to events generated by UI controls?  This will be the key to the solution.

Comment: No, if i select todays date in picker one then i go to picker two and select the date there as well. But now i can go back in time with the second date. (I updated my question since not only date but time is an issue here as well)

Comment: Time is an issue, and yet you are still learning?  Those conditions don't seem compatible.

Comment: I would like to comprehend your "connection" between two UIDatePickers like follow:

Once you've picked the beginning time in the beginTimePicker, the endTimePicker should set it's minimumDate to the beginning time. Therefore there would be no chance that the user is able to pick sometime earlier than the beginning time.

I'm just too drunk to proceed. Hope my answer/comment help. May the force be with you.

Comment: @trojanfoe i dont mean like i need to hurry and learn, i mean that my datepicker shows date and time.

Comment: @James haha you make me laugh. i'll look into setting the minimumDate for the beginTimePicker. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this after `[self.beginTijdTextField setInputView:beginTijdPicker];` :

```
[self.beginTijdTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(beginTijdDidChange) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

and add this method

```
-(void)beginTijdDidChange
{
    int oneDay = 1;
    NSDate *maxDateFromBeginig = [beginTijdPicker.date dateByAddingTimeInterval:60*60*24*oneDay]; //24h + beginDate
    NSDate *minDateFromBeginig = [NSDate dateWithTimeInterval:1.0 sinceDate:beginTijdPicker.date]; //1 sec + beginDate
    eindTijdPicker.maximumDate = maxDateFromBeginig;
    eindTijdPicker.minimumDate = minDateFromBeginig;
}
```

Comment: `60*60*24`? tut tut.  Plus what happens when begin date changes?

Comment: xcode wants me to replace self.beginTijdPicker with self->beginTijdPicker :/

Comment: good point trojanfoe, maybe he can set another variable and change it in showselecteddate1 and run an nstimer (1 sec) to change the maximumdate ?

Comment: No... you catch UI edit events and make changes there.

Comment: @maetsoh *She. But there should be a simpler way to achieve this i suppose?

Comment: It's giving me the following error: Property 'beginTijdPicker' not found on object of type 'TaakToevoegen *'; did you mean to access instance variable 'beginTijdPicker'?

Comment: oh yes I thought that the datepickers were properties, look at my last edit

Comment: I wish i could say it works. But i can still set startdate + time to todays date and eind date + time to yesterday :(

Comment: add `[self beginTijdDidChange];` in your `ShowSelectedDate1` method and see if it changes something ?

Comment: OMG! Sweet!! thank you soo much! it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Yeh! you can set Maximum date and minimum date to the Second UIDatePicker.

```
[datePicker setMinimumDate:minDate]; //minDate should be first date picker's date
[datePicker setMaximumDate:maxDate]; //maxDate should be 24 hrs grater than the minDate.
```

Comment: And if the first changes?

Comment: Nice..If an editing happens to the first date picker, second date textfield should clear!!   :)

Comment: Is that what will happen or what you think should happen?

Answer (score 0):

Beside the already solved problem the UI seems a bit convoluted. If it is known that one time has to be 0-24 hours after the other why not just let the user pick that, i.e. start date-time and a 0-24 hour time interval as pickers and then calculate the end date as start + interval? Seems easier to use to me.