# Current date event change value

Tags: ios, objective-c, events, nsdate

Is there a way to be notified if the field of current date is changed?

If yes how?
If not how can I do this?
I need to compare permanently an `NSDate` to the current date and know when the difference between them is 10 minutes.

**Precision:**

I have `NSDate *futurDate` for example: 05/12/2015 05:00 AM.

and current date `NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];` (05/12/2015 03:00 AM)

I need to be notified when the currentDate will be 05/12/2015 04:50 AM.

Thanks

Comment: `NSDate` objects are immutable.  They never change once they are created.  If you want to know when 10 minutes have passed, use a timer and compare the current date to a date stored when you started the timer.

Comment: are these `NSDate`s connected to `UIDatePicker`s ? `UITextField`s ? my answer here could help : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33940942/objective-c-begin-date-and-end-date-uidatepicker/

Comment: Hi @Avi, for NSDate *date, I need to know when the current date arrives 10 minutes before the date...

Comment: @Avi please see the edited question

Comment: You should actually edit your question to include what you're really after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is construct a date that is 10 minutes earlier, then use the new date as your goal.

```
NSDate *futureDate = ...;  // Tell me when it's 10 minutes before this date.
NSDate *reminderDate = [futureDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-1 * 60 * 10];  // Date 10 minutes earlier.
NSDate *now = [NSDate date];

if ([reminderDate timeIntervalSinceDate:now] < 0) {
    // It is currently within 10 minutes of future date.
} else {
    // Schedule a timer to fire in the number of seconds between
    // the current date and our desired reminder date.
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:[reminderDate timeIntervalSinceDate:now]
                                     target:self 
                                   selector:@selector(timerHandler:) 
                                   userInfo:nil 
                                    repeats:NO];
}

- (void)timerHandler:(NSTimer *)timer {
    // It's now within 10 minutes of future date.
}
```

Comment: Why not `scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:600.0`?

Comment: Using 600 obscures the specific requirement of 10 minutes.  The compiler does the work of calculating, so there's no runtime cost.

Comment: But it would be easier to use `-initWithFireDate:…`. I did not care about the runtime consumption, but the readability of code.

Comment: There are a lot of ways to write the code.  I copied that line form the other answer because that was the easiest to do at the time I wrote my answer.  As long as the algorithm is understood, readers are free to actually *gasp* learn the APIs they are using.

Comment: The code in my answer will work as you are requesting.